# How to make an app display a map with the users current location and then direct said user to a set location?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

The code I'm using at the moment is:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    openMapForPlace()
}

func openMapForPlace() {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.688607,144.890787)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
    mapItem.name = "Gladstone Park Secondary College"
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
}
```

The only thing it shows is a map of Australia and outputs this - Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4.

Comment: Maybe start by googling "iOS location tutorial"?

Comment: I did, couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

try this code, my be work for you.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

   if userLocation != nil {

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: selectedCoordinate!.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

 } else if let location = locations.first {

         mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

         locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)        
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```